# How to create SQL column names that have brackets around them

Tags: mysql, sql, brackets

I am wondering if there is an SQL command that will allow me to wrap brackets [] around existing column names.

For example, in `MyTable`, I have columns titled `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`. I want to alter these so that their new column names are `[1]`, `[2]`, `[3]`, `[4]`.

Is there an SQL statement that lets me do this?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?  Why do you want your columns to have square brackets in them?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. With a question like this about SQL, you should please make sure you identify the DBMS you are using (probably MS SQL Server, but...).  Also, I wonder what you mean by wrapping brackets around column names. Presumably, you're thinking of some sort of SQL editor.  How accurate an analysis are you expecting. Personally, I think you'd be better off choosing more meaningful column names; these ones are going to cause endless grief because `1` (especially) is a number that can appear in SQL as a number. Note that to reference the columns you must use `[1]` etc already.

Comment: Although I don't see any reason why this wouldn't be possible. I would definately advise against naming your columns `1..4`. These names are totally undescriptive and if you want to store more values of the same type you should probably store them in rows instead of columns.

Comment: I'm trying to collect data from MySQL into MATLAB.I have been using: tbread('tablename', cols, vecs, '') to create MATLAB variables with the table's column names and their data inside.I have been unable to retrieve numeric column names and their data.I realize that there are drawbacks in using numbers to name columns because the sql commands to retrieve them do not work, but I cannot change the column names (because I am using MySQL as a backup for imported data from another source).I can make SQL commands from MATLAB.I figured i would add [] to the column names so that i don't corrupt my data

Comment: im using mym to interface MySQL and MATLAB

Comment: the columns arent actually 1..4. each column name has about 11 numbers that correspond to code im writing in matlab. i just need to retrieve all their data!!!

Answer (score 0):

On Sql Server, this does the job:

```
select 1 AS "[1]"
```

This, of course, selects the literal integer 1. To select a field called 1 you'd need to do this:

```
select [1] AS "[1]"
```

I agree with the commenters, the whole idea seems fraught with peril but if you're dealing with legacy/proprietary data sometimes you don't have a choice.

If you want to do this automatically, you can run the following code (or make it into a stored procedure for re-use):

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Comma AS VARCHAR(2)
    DECLARE @Sql as VARCHAR(5000)
    DECLARE @Column AS VARCHAR(50)

    SET @Sql = 'SELECT '
    SET @Comma = ''

    DECLARE ColCsr CURSOR FOR
        SELECT COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable' 

    OPEN ColCsr
    FETCH NEXT FROM ColCsr INTO @Column

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Sql = @Sql + @Comma + @Column + ' AS "[' + @Column + ']"'
        SET @Comma = ', '
        FETCH NEXT FROM ColCsr INTO @Column
    END
    CLOSE ColCsr
    DEALLOCATE ColCsr

    SET @Sql = @Sql + ' FROM MyTable'

    EXEC (@Sql)
END
```

Comment: is there a command such as select * AS "[]"....this way i dont have to list all the column nameS?

Comment: No, if you're renaming the fields you have to do it manually.

Comment: what if i were to add @ to the beginning of every column name?

Comment: However, it is easily acheived using T-SQL - see my example that I added. You can use @ or format the field name however you want.

Comment: Okay, I see you've now tagged this with MySQL. That would have been handy to know earlier. My T-SQL code is for Sql Server but I assume there would be a similar way to do this in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server I guess you could do something like this:

```
select [1] as [[1]]], [2] as [[2]]] ...
```

Seems like an odd requirement though

Comment: wouldnt this create a table with columns that have [columnname]? what about doing this to existing columns

Answer (score 0):

Brackets are an SQL Server/T-SQL syntax. The columns names doesn't have brackets as part of the name. Brackets are just used when writing an SQL statement to allow that column name can be some reserved keyword. This way you can have a column named "table":

```
CREATE TABLE [MyTable](
[Table] [nchar](10) NULL, 
[Column] [nchar](10) NULL, 
)
GO

SELECT [Table], [Column] from MyTable
GO
```

Comment: i have 1,000 columns with numeric names. i cannot change them because i did not create them. is there anyway i can retrieve all of them?